# How Can I add music file to music player playlist from application

Tags: iphone, audio, audio-player

As i searched a lot that i can access music library for picking a song but can't add a recorded song file to the playlist of it.

Is it possible to add file to that playlist ? iPod api library permits it or not..........

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/iPodLibraryAccess_Guide/AboutiPodLibraryAccess/AboutiPodLibraryAccess.html

Comment: http://mobisoftinfotech.com/integrate-music-player-in-iphone/

Comment: I am not asking integrating music player in iPhone app. I asked , Can I add recorded music file from an App to music library ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you would like to distribute your app through AppStore, it is

- neither possible to access iPod library through file system calls since iOS applications are sandboxed (which means you can't directly write a file into the iTunes library on the device, only to write files in your application's space)
- nor the iPod api could provide this feature for you, it only lets you read the library, not write to it.

If you plan it on jailbroken devices you can use [libipodimport](https://github.com/H2CO3/libipodimport) library.